# Management Data Warehouse Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, management-data-warehouse

We have a MDW Database in our PROD Server of size 40GB.

I can see all the collector Jobs are not running properly and the purging MDW job.

```
mdw_purge_data_[ManagementDWH]
```

is not running saying the owner does not have access to server.

When I access the Tables in MDW Database I can see all the tables are updated few months ago.

Can anyone help me with below queries :

1. Do we really need MDW Database ?
2. What if I delete my existing MDW Database (Unless we need to troubleshoot any performance issues) ?

Please let me know if is required to keep the MDW Database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's our place to make the decision of you needing MDW or not. Only you and your team with your knowledge of your environments can make that decision, but if you're not using it then I would try to find out who installed it, for what reason and if that reason is still valid.

If you do decide to remove it, be aware there are some 'problems' with the uninstall. See [this Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/334180/data-collector-remove-data-collector-to-remove-associated-objects) for all the pain people have suffered over the years with the uninstall.

You've tagged 2008 R2 and 2014, so the version of SQL Server that MDW is installed on will decide how many issues you will encounter when trying to remove MDW. 2012 added 3 stored procedures to help the process but even they don't quite remove everything. [This TechNet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27572.removing-sql-server-management-data-warehouse-data-collector.aspx) covers the problem and [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2473/removing-the-sql-server-management-data-warehouse/) covers the solution for 2008 and 2012.

Comment: After reading the links,seriously, I never Imagined this was such a concern to mess with MDW.Thanks a lot @James Anderson,for hinting me on the serious points with MDW.Will work on these lines and it was real helpful.

Comment: @SQLBoy No worries, glad it was useful.